# Cannot open Perl script "Configure": no such file or directory

Tags: openssl

How to install openSSL on Windows-32 bit?

This is what I have done so far:

1. Downloaded openSSL source code from http://www.openssl.org/source/ and unzip it using 7-zip
2. Download & install ActiveState Perl @ ActiveState Perl and added `C:\perl\bin\`.
3. Run `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat` to get Visual Studio environment setup.
4. Run `perl Configure VC-WIN32 no-asm – -prefix=C:\openssl-1.0.1b`.

This command gives me the error `cannot open perl script "Configure": no such file or directory`.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: "...no such file or directory..." - where did you unpack OpenSSL, and which directory were you in when you ran `perl Configure VC-WIN32 no-asm`?

Comment: It simply means that perl is not able to find `Configure` file. Please make ensure that `Configure` file is in OpenSSL folder.

Comment: Solved... i need to go to openSSL directory because Configure file is the part of openSSL.

Comment: Same problem. Downloaded openssl-1.0.1j into d:\libs\openssl-1.0.1j and made it the current dir in a dos prompt. There is no Configure* file in that archive :(

Comment: I can't find configure in my OpenSSL directory too. Where should it be?

Answer (score 5):

Here is what I did to fix this error:

- I executed the command in **Visual Studio Command Prompt** instead of
  a regular CMD.
- To run to the Visual Studio Command Prompt click `start` -> `All
  programs` -> `Microsoft Visual Studio 2010` -> `Visual Studio Tools`
  -> `Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010)`
- Also, Make sure you are in the directory where the file **Configure** is located.

The command got executed with no error

Answer (score 2):

1) You should run NASM as administrator. Its must have.

2) Switch folder to downloaded openSSL files (Folder with files like README, INSTALL, NOTES, etc.)

3) Run:

`perl Configure {YOUR CONFIGURATION}`