# What does perl configure mean

Tags: perl, activeperl

Forgive me this newbie question.

After installing ActivePerl for Windows. I try to understand the command `perl configure ....` with the command `perldoc perl`. But didn't found anything about `configure` option. I also try the command `perldoc perl configure`. But It doesn't work. Shows `No documentation found for "configure".`

Comment: where are you seeing "configure" used?

Comment: It seems `configure` is a perl script ? Because I found configure.pl in the same folder of Perl.exe.

Comment: @ysth the whole command line is `perl Configure VC-WIN32 --prefix=C:\Build-OpenSSL-VC-32.`

Comment: @cHao found `configure.pl` file in the `bin`

Comment: Forgive me I can't read perl script. What is the configure.pl doing ?Please tell me more about it .thanks.

Comment: It is my mistake. The configure not belong to perl environment. It belong to the openssl package. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21697273/cannot-open-perl-script-configure-no-such-file-or-directory.

Comment: Please be aware that `Configure`, `configure` and `configure.pl` are three different filenames. They could be three different files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://community.activestate.com/node/7573 it looks to me like the Configure being talked about is a script included with and used to build the OpenSSL source; it is not part of perl or the perl distribution.

Though the perl source does include a Configure script, that is a shell script used to build perl itself, and nothing to do with the Configure you are looking for.

I don't know what the configure.pl you see is, but it is also likely not what you are looking for.